# Cant get onchange to Validate

Tags: javascript, validation, onchange

Hey I'm using the onchange attribute or w.e they are called, and it wont vailidate in  XHTML 1.0 Strict when using the w3c validater which i have to use, i need a way around this so that my code will still work, and validate.
 the error is:
Line 211, Column 32: there is no attribute "onchange"

and here are the values it effects or w/e (not in proper order just cut and pasted)

```
Cost of Registration:<input id="cost" name="cost" readonly="readonly"/>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="monday" name="Attending" value="monday" />Monday<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" name="Attending" value="tuesday" />Tuesday<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="wesnesday" name="Attending"value="wednesday"/>Wesnesday<b/></p>
```

i have another onchange that the validater seems to have no problems with

```
<p>
 <select id="regcat" onchange="autofill()">
 <option value="UWS Student">UWS Student</option>
 <option value="Student at another institution">Student at another institution</option>
 <option value="UWS Academic">UWS Academic</option>
 <option value="Other UWS Staff">Other UWS Staff</option>
 <option value="Academic from another Institution">Academic from another   Institution</option>
 <option value="Professional">Professional</option>
 <option value="Retired">Retired</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Can find a fix for this anywhere.(sorry for grammar and spelling its very late)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your event handler through JavaScript instead of the attribute.  If you're using jQuery:

```
$('#regcat').change(autofill);
```

You'll want this in a document ready wrapper if you're not already using one.  The shortest way:

```
$(function() {
    $('#regcat').change(autofill);
});
```

If you're not using jQuery, you'll use the [addEventListener method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) (but again, you'll need to account for the DOM being ready).  If you're not using jQuery AND you need to support IE <9, you'll unfortunately have to also add in the [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call within a conditional comment wrapper.

Comment: i wasnt using jquery i fixed by taking it out of body puting into the where that select was and on all the <input> tags for the checkboxes